# Angular js two way data binding issue to manage "text box" to "label" change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am using data model having "edit" field. And based on "edit" value i either use text box or label. I want that once user click "ok" after edit then text box should change to label. However somehow it is not working. Following is jsfiddle example. Please help.

http://jsfiddle.net/dilipkumar2k6/zEdY8/2/`">JSFiddleLink

Comment: i tried a lot however not able to edit jsfiddle URL properly. I will try to learn more on editor. However you can copy the jsfiddle URL for reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've modified your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lpiepiora/zEdY8/3/), you have to change it to something like this

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="controller" id="contentsDivID">
<div ng-repeat="chapter in chapters">
<ng:switch on="chapter.edit">
            <div ng:switch-when="true">
                <input type="text" ng-model="chapter.title" ng-model="chapter.title" />                
                <a ng-click="addChapter($index);"><i class="icon-ok"></i></a>
            </div>          
            <div ng:switch-when="undefined">
                    <label>{{chapter.title}}</label>
            </div>
            </ng:switch>        
    </div>       
</div>
```

Then your JavaScript code to this

```
function controller($scope)
{
    $scope.chapters=[
            {
                "_id": "567456746",
                "title": "Growth and Development",
                "type": "section",
                "edit":true
            },
            {
                "_id": "34563465345",
                "title": "Links between Areas of Development",
                "type": "section"
            },
            {
                "_id": "8776545645",
                "title": "Characteristics of Development",
                "thumbnail": "/xopus/images/templates/media-1-top-right.png",
                "type": "section"
            }
        ];

    $scope.addChapter = function(index) {
        $scope.chapters[index].edit = undefined;
    }
}
```

You may want to checkout [angular concepts documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts) - it should give you some highlight on how angular tracks changes to the model.